# Add events from database to fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar to display different type of events for my organization. All of the event are in a database and i use this php file to get the events.

```
<?php
$xml = array();
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');
if(!$conn){
  $e = oci_error();
  trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);  
}else{
  //echo "connection made";  
}
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'EventTracker');
if(!$db_selected){
  die("database not selected");
}else{
    $query="SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `event_deletion` = 1";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(!$result){
        trigger_error("dbget: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
        return false;   
    }else{
        while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $obj = array();
            array_push($obj, $row['event_ID']);
            array_push($obj, $row['event_name']);
            array_push($obj, $row['event_start']);
            array_push($obj, $row['event_end']);
            array_push($xml, $obj);
            //print_r($xml);
        }
         generateXML($xml);
    }
}
//echo  json_encode($xml);
function generateXML($array){
    $xmlString = "events:";
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array);$i++){
        $obj = $array[$i];
        //print_r($obj);
        $set = "{
            id: '" . $obj[0] . "'," .
            "title:'" . $obj[1] . "'," .
            "start:'" . $obj[2] . "'," .
            "end:'" . $obj[3] . "'"."},";
            //echo $set . "\r\n";
        $xmlString = $xmlString . $set;
    }
    return $xmlString = $xmlString;
}
?>
```

I am trying to load the string generated from generateXML to the jquery call for fullcalendar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo generateXML($xml); ?>
console.log(data)
function getDates(){
    return data;    
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        //defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [getDates()],
    })

});
</script>
```

Not sure what the problem is but any clues or suggestions would help.

Answer (score 0):

What error(s) are you getting? Show us what the results of getDates() looks like. It has to be formatted as per the fullcalendar [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/) and [example](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.2/demos/basic-views.html) is has to be something along the lines of

```
            {
                title: 'Event #1',
                start: '2015-02-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event #2',
                start: '2015-02-07',
                end: '2015-02-10'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event #n',
                start: '2015-02-07',
                end: '2015-02-10'
            }
```